# How to get element from JsonResult using loop (Swift 3)

Tags: swift3

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
```

When debugger comes on above line, in debug console there is ->

```
jsonResult =(NSDictionary) 2 key/value pairs
>[0] = “CompanyList” : 140 elements
>[1] = “StatusTable” : 1 element
```

jsonResult contains 2 array

Now i wanna to traverse CompanyList using Loop
like

```
let arr_CompanyList = [CompanyList]()
for dictionary in json as! [[CompanyList]]
{
  //arr_CompanyList.append(dictionary)            
}
```

but is gives error

Here is CompanyList Class

```
public class CompanyList {
    public var companyAlt_Key : Int?
    public var company_Name : String?
    public var tableName : String?
}
```

How should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert your `JSON` Array response to directly your Class objects array, you need to create your custom class object from the JSON response. Also instead of using `NSDictionary` in swift use native type `Dictionary`.

```
if let jsonResult = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData!, options: [])) as? [String:Any] {
    if let companyList = jsonResult["CompanyList"] as? [[String:Any]] {
        //Now loop through the companyList array
        let arr_CompanyList = companyList.flatMap(CompanyList.init)
        //To get array of companyname
        let companyNames = companyList.flatMap { $0["Company_Name"] as? String }
        print(companyNames)
    }
}
```

Now simply add one `init` with your `CompanyList` class like this way.

```
public class CompanyList {
    public var companyAlt_Key : Int?
    public var company_Name : String?
    public var tableName : String?


    init?(dictionary: [String:Any]) {
        guard let companyAltKey = dictionary["CompanyAlt_Key"] as? Int, 
           let companyName = dictionary["Company_Name"] as? String,
           let tableName = dictionary["TableName"] as? String else {
               return nil
        }
        self.companyAlt_Key = companyAltKey
        self.company_Name = companyName
        self.tableName = tableName
    }
}
```

**Note:** Inside `init?` method with `dictionary` you need to access your key that contains value according to your class property.

Comment: @DilipJangid From where you are getting this Jsonresult, if it is already array of `CompanyList` then what do you want.

Comment: @DilipJangid if your array is already type of `CompanyList` then what you want do with it, You want to convert it to JSON response?

Comment: @DilipJangid For that you need to show me the console log of this statement `print(jsonResult["CompanyList"])` add this print statement and show me the console log of it, Note don't cast the response simply add print like my one.

Comment: @DilipJangid Then your array is array of dictionary not the array of `CompanyList` objects.

Comment: @DilipJangid Welcome mate :)